# Выбирается одно значение django python

Tags: python, mysql, django

Делаю авторизацию по ключу, в базе данных лежать 2 ключа, но почему-то он авторизуется только по последнему

```
def index(request):

all_keys_list = Key.objects.raw("SELECT *, activation_key FROM main_key")
# for k in Key.objects.raw("SELECT id, activation_key FROM main_key"):
#  print(k.activation_key)



if (request.method == "POST"):
    #for k in Key.objects.raw("SELECT id, activation_key FROM main_key"):

    #qq = Key.objects.raw("SELECT *, activation_key FROM main_key")
     #print(k.activation_key)
    #for w in qq:
    key = request.POST.get("name")
    for k in Key.objects.raw("SELECT id, activation_key FROM main_key"):
    #if qq.filter(activation_key=activation_key).exists():
     #activation_key = qq
     print(k.activation_key)
    if (key == k.activation_key):

     return HttpResponse("<h2>Hello, {0}</h2>".format(key))
    else:
        keyform = Key()
    #return render(request, "main/index.html", {'form': keyform})
        return render(request, "main/index.html", {'form': keyform, 'all_keys_list': all_keys_list})

else:
    return render(request, "main/index.html", {'all_keys_list': all_keys_list})
```

Принт возвращает 2 числа. Что может быть?

Comment: мне кажется или if вне цикла остался?

Comment: Проверил операторы if else, они стоят друг под другом где это требуется, но не работает всё равно

Comment: отредактируйте код в впоросе. Расстваьте правильные отступы 1 в 1 как у вас в проекте

Comment: Один в один код, как в проекте

Comment: перед for 4 пробела, перед print 5, перед if опять 4

Comment: А помогло) спасибо. Как ты так. Только перед for не нужно пробелы